# How to download MP3 files with ASP.NET MVC 5 & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have successfully done the upload bit - uploaded the MP3 files to my SQL Server, but I need help in downloading the files.... I use the following code to upload the MP3 file

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Artist,Album")] TrackUpload trackUpload, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var song = new File
                {
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                    FileType = FileType.Songs,
                    ContentType = upload.ContentType
                };
                using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                {
                    song.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                }
                trackUpload.Files = new List<File> { song };
            }
            db.TrackUploads.Add(trackUpload);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cant save changes.");
    }
    return View(trackUpload);
}
```

**It is working fine which meaning the file stores in Database, Now how do i download the MP3 file from sql db using entity framework**

Comment: write this entity TrackUpload.cs i want to see it

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto give you the correct answer or the hint to the answer. one thing if the files are large then do not store them as blob read about filestream and store them in FileStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download an MP3 file from MVC controller, make sure you have set MIME type of `FileContentResult` either as `audio/mp3`, `audio/mpeg3` or `audio/x-mpeg3` (see http://filext.com/file-extension/MP3 for details).

Here is a simple controller code defining file downloading scenario:

```
/*
 *  assume Id becomes file ID key to download
 *  this code provides simple download function by returning FileContentResult with proper MIME type
 */
public FileContentResult DownloadFile(int Id) 
{
    // assume FileContext is your file list DB context with FileName property (file name + extension, e.g. Sample.mp3)
    using (FileContext db = new FileContext())
    {
        var download = db.TrackUploads.Where(x => x.ID == Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (download != null) 
        {
            // remove this line if you want file download on the same page
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + download.FileName);
            return File(download.FileName, "audio/mp3");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Addendum**

To get MIME type from file extension before downloading, this code part may work:

```
if (download != null) 
{
    String mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(download.FileName);
    ...
    // other tasks
    ...
    return File(download.FileName, mimeType);
}
```

Reference: [view and download File from sql db using Entity FrameWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822058/view-and-download-file-from-sql-db-using-entity-framework) (with adjustment for MP3 extension)

Comment: Thanks, can you kindly help out with the html view markup too?

Comment: Show your razor markup view in your question and I'll give some try to help. I suggest you using a form with download button such like `@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))` to download MP3 files.